# Advice on Php codeigniter insert query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form and it's been bugging for a while now, when i have all the information filled up in the forms it seems to insert it very quick, however if one or more fields are empty it doesn't work at all
the query i am using to insert into the database is. i am trying to figure out if i can use Insert_delay and maybe it will solve the problem? any possible solutions or changes i need to do

```
function student($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['name']       = $this->input->post('name');         
        $data['sex']        = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['address']    = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']      = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['email']      = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']   = $this->input->post('password');
        $data['year']       = $this->input->post('year');
        $data['rate']   = $this->input->post('rate');
        $data['class_id']   = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $data['class_id2']  = $this->input->post('class_id2');
        $data['class_id3']  = $this->input->post('class_id3');
        $data['class_id4']  = $this->input->post('class_id4');
        $data['parent_id']  = $this->input->post('parent_id');
        $data['roll']       = $this->input->post('roll');
        $this->db->insert_('student', $data);
        $student_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('Student_added_successfully'));
        $this->email_model->account_opening_email('student', $data['email']); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student_add/' . $data['class_id'], 'refresh');
```

Comment: However even in case of failure sometimes data is added to the table

Comment: It depends on db table fields default value too. If something is expected it must be passed. Otherwise, if data is not mandatory, default value of field can be set to `NULL`.

Comment: I have set all of them to null by default. and left only PK and FK which are not. but still the same issue

Comment: No form validation needed? @Anasbzr

Comment: I tried removing it but it didn't change much. the issue seems to be with my host as when i run it in localhost it seems to be with no issues.

Comment: Aggre with @Tpojka . by the way you can check your query in profiler. you can put profiler on your __CONSTRUCT() class of controller.

Comment: $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);// to set profiler. then try to runing your query manual.

Comment: @Anasbzr is this your controller ??

Comment: which error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In controller**

```
function student($param1, $param2 $param3 )
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
    {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        if($param1 == 'create') {

            $result = $this->model_name->insert_data();

            if ($result != FALSE) {

                $email => $this->input->post('email');                  
                $confirm = $this->email_model->account_opening_email('student', $email); # do same as insert

                if ($confirm != FALSE) {

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('Student_added_successfully'));
                    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student_add/' . $data['class_id'], 'refresh');
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Mail send failed";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                echo "param1 is not create";
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function insert_data()
{
    # to isert data, I add them in to one array
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
        'rate' => $this->input->post('rate'),
        'class_id' => $this->input->post('class_id'),
        'class_id2' => $this->input->post('class_id2'),
        'class_id3' => $this->input->post('class_id3'),
        'class_id4' => $this->input->post('class_id4'),
        'parent_id' => $this->input->post('parent_id'),
        'roll' => $this->input->post('roll')
    );

    if (!$this->db->insert('student', $data)) {

        # insert FAILED
        return FALSE;
    }
    else{

        # insert SUCCESS        
        $slast_id = $this->db->insert_id(); # get last insert ID
        return = $slast_id;
    }

}
```